# Can I pop up an interactive matplotlib plot from a flask app running from an Anaconda prompt without any HTML pages

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

In my past searches I've found example code for using matplotlib to save a .png file and then display that .png file in an html page that links to a flask app.  I'm hoping there is an example out there that allows my flask app (running from an anaconda prompt console window) to pop up a plot from matplotlib that updates when the server gets new data.  I seem to have gotten close in that a small blank window opens up, but nothing is displayed.  Are there any example projects that do this, or am I wasting my time?  Perhaps there is no other way to do this other than generating an HTML page.

Comment: You cannot open a "matplotlib window" through a webserver. What is the overarching problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have the server running processing data that is coming in.  I'd like to plot that data with an interactive matplotlib window.  It looks like I can launch the window from the code in the flask app, but it is blank which leads me to believe this should be possible, but I just don't have the right recipe.

Comment: If you want to serve plots with Flask, you need an interactive plotting library for web pages. Check out [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/).